# Group by query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have got 2 tables, `Security` and `SecurityTransactions`.

**`Security`**:

```
create table security(SecurityId int, SecurityName varchar(50));

insert into security values(1,'apple');

insert into security values(2,'google');

insert into security values(3,'ibm');
```

**`SecurityTable`**:

```
create table SecurityTransactions(SecurityId int, Buy_sell boolean, Quantity int);

insert into securitytransactions values ( 1 , false, 100 );

insert into securitytransactions values ( 1 , true, 20 );

insert into securitytransactions values ( 1 , false, 50 );

insert into securitytransactions values ( 2 , false, 120 );
```

I want to find out the security name and it's no of appearance in `SecurityTransactions`.

The answer is below:

```
SecurityName | Appearance
apple        | 3
google       | 1
```

I wrote the below sql query :

```
select S.SecurityName, count(t.securityID) as Appearance
from security S inner join securitytransactions t on S.SecurityId = t.SecurityId
group by t.SecurityId, S.SecurityName;
```

this query gave me the desired result, but it was still rejected by a person saying group by should have been `s.securityName`. why is it so ?

EDIT :

Which one do you this is correct and why ?

a. group by t.SecurityId, S.securityName

b. group by t.SecurityId

c. group by S.securityName

Comment: Thanks Willem for editing the question !

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about `GROUP BY`. MySQL's old default behavior is lenient and permits you to include columns in `SELECT` not present in `GROUP BY`, but most other RDBMS would reject that query. Additionally, the behavior is _off by default_ in MySQL 5.7 so it is not recommended to rely on it, and a bad habit to have when you switch to another RDMBS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907729/mysql-5-7-only-full-group-by

Comment: Michael, what would be the right query then ?

Comment: Grumble. Question changed materially after I answered it. There's nothing wrong with the query as changed. The "person" is wrong. It's fine to group by columns that don't appear in the result set.

Comment: O.Jones, Could you please elaborate on why the query I have written is right ?

Answer (score 2):

According to ANSI SQL, if you use a `group by` clause your select list may only contain items in the `group by` clause, single row transformations thereof, or aggregate expressions. MySQL is non-standard, and allows other columns too. In this case it happened to produce the right answer, as there's a 1:1 relationship between the `SecuirtyId` and `SecurityName`, but generally speaking, this is a bad practice that will make your code hard to understand at best, and unpredictable at worst.

EDIT:
To address the edited question - grouping by both `SecuirtyId` and `SecurityName` isn't technically wrong, it's just redundant. Since there's a 1:1 relationship between the two columns, adding the `SecurityId` column to the `group by` clause won't change the result, and will just confuse people reading the query.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my original query with the group by clause now involving both fields, could you please suggest now?

Comment: Mureinik, what if I group by with just SecurityId ? in that case, will it be right ? Also, do you mean I should just write group by SecurityName ?

Comment: @PramTal `group by SecurityId;` would be (technically) wrong (although some mysql versions allow it); `group by SecurityId, SecurityName;` would technically work in your case (so isn't technically wrong) - but there is actually something to consider: the two version will behave differently if you can have two companies with the same name/different id. Anyway, currently it doesn't belong there logically: You want to group by the name. So group by the name. `group by t.SecurityId+1, t.SecurityId+3, S.SecurityName;` would technically work too, but you would ask yourself why I would write THAT.